# Erasing 2-lines pattern with sed/grep/whatever

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, cvs

I have a huge cvs log file which, cleaned from the useless info, reads something like

```
Working file: unmodifiedfile1.c
================
Working file: modifiedfile1.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.3
Fixed some bug
================
Working file: unmodifiedfile2.h
================
Working file: modifiedfile2.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.1
Added some feature
================
Working file: unmodifiedfile3.h
```

I would like to clean the lines related to unmodified files:

```
Working file: modifiedfile1.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.3
Fixed some bug
================
Working file: modifiedfile2.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.1
Added some feature
================
```

The pattern to match is

```
Working file: FILENAME
================
```

What i've been able to do up to now is the following:

```
sed '/Working file:/ N ; s/\n/PLACEHOLDER/' changelog.txt |
grep -v 'PLACEHOLDER===' |
sed 's/PLACEHOLDER/\n/
```

I'm sure however there is a cleaner solution that my sed ignorance precludes me... ( also, a bonus would be being able to erase the very latest line if necessary)

P.S.

An output ending with:

```
================
Working file: unmodifiedfile3.h
```

is also acceptable

Comment: can you add the expected output for clarity? add a separate one if it will be different for the bonus question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/Working file:/ N ; s/\n/PLACEHOLDER/' changelog.txt |
grep -v 'PLACEHOLDER===' |
sed 's/PLACEHOLDER/\n/
```

can indeed be shortened to:

```
$ sed '/Working file:/{N;/===/d}' changelog.txt 
Working file: modifiedfile1.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.3
Fixed some bug
================
Working file: modifiedfile2.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.1
Added some feature
================
Working file: unmodifiedfile3.h
```

- To remove all lines containing `Working file:` and following line if it contains `===` as well as final line if it contains `Working file:`

Thanks @ilkkachu for the suggestion. If the pattern needs to be matched at beginning of line, use `^Working file:`

```
$ cat ip.txt 
Working file: 123
================
Working file: f1
----------------------------------
revision 1.3
Fixed some bug
================
Working file: abc
================
Working file: file
----------------------------------
revision 1.1
Added some feature
================
Working file: xyz

$ sed '/Working file:/{N;/===/d}' ip.txt | sed '${/Working file:/d}' 
Working file: f1
----------------------------------
revision 1.3
Fixed some bug
================
Working file: file
----------------------------------
revision 1.1
Added some feature
================
```

Comment: Your initial sed solution was exactly what I was after. However the tweaks using 'unmodified' are wrong, the filenames are not made like that, I wasn't probably clear enough.

Comment: @Davide, I would then suggested to undo this answer as accepted, and edit your question with a better example... that way it helps others trying to solve a similar problem

Comment: I think you could use `${/^Working file/d};` in the beginning of the `sed` to remove the final line if it starts with `Working file`. I'd put the beginning-of-line anchor to the other `/Working file/` pattern, too, though the sed would still match that if the final line of an actual commit message started with `Working file`...

Answer (score 3):

## sed

This should come close to what you are after:

```
<cvslog sed -n '/Working file/ { N; /\n=\+$/b; :a; N; /\n=\+$/!ba; p; }'
```

Output:

```
Working file: modifiedfile1.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.3
Fixed some bug
================
Working file: modifiedfile2.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.1
Added some feature
================
```

#### Explanation

Here is the same `sed` script with comments:

```sed
/Working file/ {
  N                 # append next line to pattern space
  /\n=\+$/b         # is it a file separator -> next file
  :a
  N                 # append next line to pattern space
  /\n=\+$/!ba       # isn't it a file separator -> read next line
  p                 # otherwise print accumulated text
}
```

## awk

If you tell `awk` to use the file separator line as the record separator (`RS`), it becomes fairly straightforward to define a sensible selection criteria:

```
<cvslog awk 'NF>2' RS='\n=+\n' FS='\n' ORS='\n\n'
```

Output:

```
Working file: modifiedfile1.h  
----------------------------------
revision 1.3
Fixed some bug

Working file: modifiedfile2.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.1
Added some feature
```

#### bash and coreutils

Just for fun:

```
csplit cvslog '/=\{16\}/1' '{*}'
wc -l xx* | 
head -n-1 | 
while read n f; do 
  if (( n > 2 )); then 
    cat $f
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
Working file: modifiedfile1.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.3
Fixed some bug
================
Working file: modifiedfile2.h
----------------------------------
revision 1.1
Added some feature
================
```

Comment: Haha I guess you like text processing.

Comment: @OgrishMan: who doesn't? :-)

Comment: Very good answer, but for the time being I accepted the other one as to me the sed script is easier to understand